# Makefile: create a build directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a C++ project with the source files spanning many directories, and with interdependencies in the headers (the headers of one directory include headers from other directory source).

I have a makefile looking like this :

```
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17
SRC = *.cpp ./num_utils/*.cpp ./shapes/*.cpp ./data_utils/*.cpp
all: $(SRC)
    $(CXX)  $(CFLAGS)  $(SRC)  -o main $(LDFLAGS)
```

I want to create a `build` directory where `.o` files get output, and modify the `makefile` so that I do not recompile every single file with every call to `make`

I get confused reading the docs, please help or point me to a beginner-friendly tutorial

Comment: `mkdir build` , You now have a "build" directory 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `makefile` is probably only dedicated to gnu-make (because of
the `wildcard`, `patsubst`, `dir` builtin commands and `ifeq`) in a unix environment (because of `mkdir -p`, `rm -rf`).

It recreates below the `build` directory the same directory hierarchy as the source files.

According to further questions in the comments, the ability to
choose between a debug build (`opt=0` by default) and a release build
(`opt=1` on the command line) has been added.

```
opt=0

CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++17
SRC=${wildcard *.cpp ./num_utils/*.cpp ./shapes/*.cpp ./data_utils/*.cpp}
OBJ=${patsubst %.cpp,build/%.o,${SRC}}

ifeq (${opt},0)
  CFLAGS+=-g
else
  CFLAGS+=-O3
endif

all: ${OBJ}
    ${CXX}  ${CFLAGS} ${OBJ} -o main ${LDFLAGS}

build/%.o : %.cpp
    mkdir -p ${dir $@}
    ${CXX} -o $@ $< -c ${CFLAGS}

clean :
    rm -rf main build
```

```
$ make clean
rm -rf main build
$ tree
.
├── data_utils
│   ├── f3.cpp
│   └── f33.cpp
├── main.cpp
├── makefile
├── num_utils
│   ├── f1.cpp
│   └── f11.cpp
└── shapes
    ├── f2.cpp
    └── f22.cpp

3 directories, 8 files
$ make 
mkdir -p build/
g++ -o build/main.o main.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -g
mkdir -p build/./num_utils/
g++ -o build/./num_utils/f1.o num_utils/f1.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -g
mkdir -p build/./num_utils/
g++ -o build/./num_utils/f11.o num_utils/f11.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -g
mkdir -p build/./shapes/
g++ -o build/./shapes/f2.o shapes/f2.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -g
mkdir -p build/./shapes/
g++ -o build/./shapes/f22.o shapes/f22.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -g
mkdir -p build/./data_utils/
g++ -o build/./data_utils/f3.o data_utils/f3.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -g
mkdir -p build/./data_utils/
g++ -o build/./data_utils/f33.o data_utils/f33.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -g
g++ -g build/main.o build/./num_utils/f1.o build/./num_utils/f11.o build/./shapes/f2.o build/./shapes/f22.o build/./data_utils/f3.o build/./data_utils/f33.o -o main 
$ make clean
rm -rf main build
$ make opt=1
mkdir -p build/
g++ -o build/main.o main.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -O3
mkdir -p build/./num_utils/
g++ -o build/./num_utils/f1.o num_utils/f1.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -O3
mkdir -p build/./num_utils/
g++ -o build/./num_utils/f11.o num_utils/f11.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -O3
mkdir -p build/./shapes/
g++ -o build/./shapes/f2.o shapes/f2.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -O3
mkdir -p build/./shapes/
g++ -o build/./shapes/f22.o shapes/f22.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -O3
mkdir -p build/./data_utils/
g++ -o build/./data_utils/f3.o data_utils/f3.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -O3
mkdir -p build/./data_utils/
g++ -o build/./data_utils/f33.o data_utils/f33.cpp -c -Wall -std=c++17 -O3
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -O3 build/main.o build/./num_utils/f1.o build/./num_utils/f11.o build/./shapes/f2.o build/./shapes/f22.o build/./data_utils/f3.o build/./data_utils/f33.o -o main 
$ ./main 
in main()
in f1()
in f2()
in f3()
in f11()
in f22()
in f33()
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
...
```

Comment: Thank You. But where is `build` directory created?

Comment: @volatile the `mkdir -p` command that precedes the compilation.

Comment: @volatile I added a trace of execution.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. Last question, how would you do to compile a debug and release version? (I mean one version with `-g` and ne optimized? What would be the best practice here?

Comment: @volatile I edited consequently for the ability to choose between a debug build and a release build. You may change the `build` directory according if you find this relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a template like this, where a list of object files is dynamically created from the C++ source files using [wildcard and patsubt](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html). You can then use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples) to build the object files automatically. Specify a dependency for default `make` command to check if any in `$(OBJS)` needs building to avoid rebuilds:

```
OBJ=obj/
SRC=src/
INCLUDE=include/
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard $(SRC)*.cpp))

$(OBJ)%.o : $(SRC)%.cpp
    g++ -c $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@

all: $(OBJS)  
    g++ main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please generalize your example for the case where there are many source directories below `src/`?